# Can I use custom Angular pipe outside of directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, formatting

I am currently formatting the response from the server inside of my component using Angular decimal pipe, like so:

Component.ts

```
private formatCells(responseData) {
    for (let i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
        if  (responseData[i].value === 0) {
            responseData[i].value = this.decimalPipe.transform(responseData[i].value '1.2-2');
        } else {
            return responseData;
        }
    }
 }
```

I am doing it this way because I am using ag-grid and cannot use a pipe in the template.

My goal is to move this logic inside of a custom pipe, and call that pipe on the responseData inside of my component.  Perhaps I do not need a custom pipe, as I am simply using decimalPipe, but I want to have the option to modify it later.

I have created a custom pipe and attempted to move the formatting functionality to the pipe, but I am not sure how to write the transform function and call it on responseData within the component.

myPipe.ts

```
import { Pipe , PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
    name: 'customDecimalFormat',
    pure: true
})

export class CustomDecimalFormatPipe extends DecimalTransform { 
    transform(value: any) {
       //...?
       return super.transform(value, "1.2-2"); 
    }
}
```

How would I move the functionality from my Component.ts into the myPipe.ts?

Comment: Why bothering writing a pipe if you are not going to use it on template? As stated on Angular docs pipes are "a way to write display-value transformations that you can declare in your HTML". Better write your transformation code in a service and use it as you wish.

Comment: I agree with you 100% but this is a req...basically they cannot use it in the template because of how ag-grid works.  So we need a custom pipe and call it on the data in the component...

Comment: I totally understood that. What I'm telling is that you don't need a pipe to do that, you only need a service with your transformation logic that you are going to inject into your components and use it there to transform your data.

Comment: Yes, agreed, it would be the same...but they want it to be a pipe for reasons I don't fully understand.  I don't have a choice I have to create a custom pipe and move that formatting logic from the component into the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although against the logic of using a pipe in the first place, I will give you the answer.

You can build your pipe like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'custom'
})
export class CustomPipe implements PipeTransform {

 constructor(public decPipe: DecimalPipe) {
  }

 transform(value: any): any {

    //here you can implement your custom logic later on as you wish     

    return this.decPipe.transform(value, "1.2-2");

  }
}
```

Now you have your custom pipe that is using Angular DecimalPipe to transform your number.

You can use it on your HTML like this:

```
<div>Used on template:<span *ngFor="let number of numbers">{{number | custom}}</span></div>
```

Or you can use it on your component code as you said you are allowed:

```
export class App implements OnInit{
  name:string;
  numbers = [1.125439];
  numberFromComponent: number;
  constructor(private customPipe: CustomPipe) {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.numberFromComponent = this.customPipe.transform(1.125439);
  }
}
```

I have made for you a working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/eEfXoXdM1OakuX1TjR1N?p=preview)

Hope this answers your question.